# get data when click on row in pageBlockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, rerender, datatable

I have a pop-up display a table with some columns (Name, ID) of Accounts for example, I want to display additional information of the selected account when I click on specific row.

I used something like this, but I must click on a column not row , and does not get the correct data.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="readCell" action="{!readCellMethod}">
        <apex:param name="rowID" value="" assignTo="{!clickedRowId}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account}" var="acc">                                    
   <apex:column headerValue="ID" value="{!acc.Id}" />
   <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!acc.Name}" onclick="readCell('{!acc.Id}')"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: Take a look at http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/forcedotcom/9780978963958/developing-visualforce-pages/ch09lev2sec7 which shows use of commandLinks in columns to pass parameters to other components on the page (or perhaps, in your case, to a controller). The commandlink approach hints to the user that something is clickable within the row.  You could have commandlinks on every column - all doing the same thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an option that still keeps your pageBlockTable. Add your jquery resource or link to it. Then, add this to head...

```
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.jQuery, '/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js')}"  />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    function clickElem(elem){
        alert($j(elem).find(".accId").html());
    }
</script>
```

Add the onRowClick to the pageBlockTable and add a styleClass to your column.

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account}" var="acc" onRowClick="clickElem(this);">                                    
   <apex:column headerValue="ID" value="{!acc.Id}" styleClass="accId" />
   <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!acc.Name}" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Woo-hoo! First post on stackexchange...

Comment: first post and it's even an answer, welcome!

Comment: Woow ! Great one .. how easy ! Thank you and Congratulations for your first answer post :)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using `<apex:repeat>` instead of `<apex:pageBlockTable>`. You'll need to use HTML table instead of visualforce components and make additional effort to add some CSS classes (like `headerRow`, `list`)  to make it look like `apex:pageBlockTable`.

So the code could like this:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="readCell" action="{!readCellMethod}">
    <apex:param name="rowID" value="" assignTo="{!clickedRowId}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="list">
    <apex:repeat value="{!account}" var="acc">
        <tr class="headerRow">
            <th class="headerRow">
                <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Id.label}"/>
            </th>
            <th class="headerRow">
                <apex:outputText value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.label}"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row{!acc.Id}">
            <script>
                document.getElementById('row{!acc.Id}').onclick = function() {
                    return readCell('{!acc.Id}')
                };
            </script>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!acc.Id}"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <apex:outputText value="{!acc.Name}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

Comment: nothing happen when I click on a row !

Comment: I was testing this solution with JS `alert` instead of `readCell` function and it was working. You can try it out by replacing it for testing purpose. Perhaps there's some issue with this method? Is a request sent to the controller at all?

Comment: I used JS alert to get readCell return value, and the result was false. And when I try to use it in SOQL query it's returns all rows with id = null

Comment: It's difficult to help you without more details. I don't know what readCellMethod does. All I'm saying that I'm pretty sure that if instead of calling readCell you would call a function showing alert with id of the source row it would work and display correct value. Maybe you need to check the debug logs to find out what's going on and what is to clickedRowId.

Comment: I tried to replace <script> block with <apex:commandLink reRender="patientSection" onclick="javascript:alert(readCell('{!acc.number}'))" value="{!acc.number}" /> . and public integer clickedRow { get; set; } in the controller.  the alert display false.

Comment: Ok, but this alert tells us what is the result of calling readCellMethod. First we need to check if the proper value is passed as a parameter to this method. That's why I suggested checking Debug Logs and/or displaying alert with Account.Id or Account.Number before/instead of calling readCell. Please try it. If it works it means there is another issue (maybe readCellMethod or with getting the response) and I think you should ask new question so that community can help you.