# On Clicking a row in a PageBlockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, pageblocktable

I have a PageBlockTable which shows a couple of rows.
On click of one of these rows I want to display the fields of row in another page block below on the same page which will have some additional fields for the user to key in. 
And then I want to create a record in another object.

How do I achieve this? How do I capture the values of the clicked row?

Below is my VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountSearch"> 
<apex:form>

<apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Please enter your details">
       <apex:inputText value="{!FName}" label="First Name"/>   
       <apex:inputText value="{!LName}" label="Last Name"/>   

    </apex:pageBlockSection>

    <apex:commandButton value="Search" id="Search" action="{!AccountSearch}"/> 
</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock title="Search Result">  
  <apex:pageblockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">  
    <apex:column >  
     <apex:outputlink value="https://cs62.salesforce.com/{!a.id}">{!a.Name}</apex:outputlink>  
    </apex:column>  
    <apex:column value="{!a.FirstName}"/>  
    <apex:column value="{!a.LastName}"/>  

  </apex:pageBlockTable>     
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Here is another example, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23333/get-data-when-click-on-row-in-pageblocktable

Comment: Hi Saroj, I looked at both the links but my requirement is a little bit different I guess. I updated the question already. So after clicking a row I want to display only few fields in another page block (not the full record). And then this page block will have a Submit/Save button to save the record in a different custom object. It's not just the display but there is user action also there on this other page block